# Generate all targets in makefile

Tags: makefile

I have Makefile:

```
INC=-I/usr/lib/boost_1_61_0
PYTHON_VERSION = 2.7
PYTHON_INCLUDE = /usr/include/python$(PYTHON_VERSION)

# location of the Boost Python include files and library
MINIREADER_INC = ./../../hdr
BOOST_INC = /usr/lib/boost_1_61_0
BOOST_LIB = /usr/lib/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib

TARGET = LoggerTestModule

$(TARGET).o: $(TARGET).cpp
        g++ -I$(PYTHON_INCLUDE) -I$(BOOST_INC) -I$(MINIREADER_INC) -fPIC -c $(TARGET).cpp --std=c++14 -g3

$(TARGET).so: $(TARGET).o
        g++ -shared -Wl,--export-dynamic $(TARGET).o ../../Release/src/Logger.o -L$(BOOST_LIB) -lboost_python -L/usr/lib/python$(PYTHON_VERSION)/config -lpython$(PYTHON_VERSION) -o $(TARGET).so --std=c++11 -g3
```

When running make -f Makefile only object file gets generated, how I can change makefile to generate both "object and library file"?

Thanks

Comment: You question is not about Makefile but about how to create a library file isn't it ? Once you know the exact command to create a library file from an object file, you can simply add it right after the compiler call that first generates the object file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a phony target and put it before the others such that it is the default goal:

```
...
TARGET = LoggerTestModule

.PHONY: all

all: $(TARGET).o $(TARGET).so

$(TARGET).o: $(TARGET).cpp
        g++ -I$(PYTHON_INCLUDE) -I$(BOOST_INC) -I$(MINIREADER_INC) -fPIC -c $(TARGET).cpp --std=c++14 -g3
...
```

**Explanations:** `all` is the default goal (first non-special target in `Makefile`) and depends on `$(TARGET).o $(TARGET).so`. So, we invoking `make` without specifying a goal, it is `all` that will be built and all its pre-requisites will be rebuilt if needed. Declaring it as a pre-requisite of the `.PHONY` special target tells make to rebuild it, even if, by accident, a file named `all` exists.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the rule for the object file, make already knows how to build it. You should probably also restructure your vars to align them with the built-in rule for linking, which you can then recycle

```
TARGET := LoggerTestModule

PYTHON_VERSION := 2.7
PYTHON_INCLUDE := /usr/include/python$(PYTHON_VERSION)
MINIREADER_INC := ./../../hdr
BOOST_INC      := /usr/lib/boost_1_61_0
BOOST_LIB      := /usr/lib/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib

CPPFLAGS := -I$(PYTHON_INCLUDE) -I$(MINIREADER_INC) -I$(BOOST_INC)
CXXFLAGS := -fPIC -std=c++14 -g3
LDFLAGS  := -L$(BOOST_LIB) -L/usr/lib/python$(PYTHON_VERSION)/config
LDLIBS   := -lboost_python -lpython$(PYTHON_VERSION)

$(TARGET).so: CC := $(CXX)
$(TARGET).so: LDFLAGS += -shared -Wl,--export-dynamic 
$(TARGET).so: $(TARGET).o ../../Release/src/Logger.o
    $(LINK.o) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```